# Add a group of concatenated rows from a table to another table. Script should work under SQL Server, Oracle, PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql, oracle, concatenation

If I have a group of columns in a table like `TEMP_TABLE (id int, text VARCHAR(max));`
and I want to add all the records of this table in another table, concatenated, what would be the best solution, considering that this script should work also for SQL Server, Oracle, PostgrSQL.

So the records are like:

```
insert into TEMP_TABLE(1, 'aaa');
insert into TEMP_TABLE(2, 'bbb');
insert into TEMP_TABLE(3, 'ccc');
...
insert into TEMP_TABLE(10, 'zzz');
```

and the result should look like

```
insert into DEST_TABLE (key,name,value) values (1,'concatenated strings','aaabbbccc...zzz')
```

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you need code that works in the different databases?  (And that is apart from the fact that it is not possible).

Comment: because the customers work under different databases and I have to make a insert that should work for all customers.

Comment: . . That is a fool's errand.  Very little code works unmodified across different databases.  You should probably create views in the individual databases to do what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to do this that is compatible with all the databases.  because your description is specific to SQL Server (`varchar(max)`), you cannot even create the table in any other database.  The solution in that database is:

```
select string_agg(text, '') within group (order by id)
from temp_table;
```

Postgres uses `string_agg()` as well, but the syntax would be:

```
select string_agg(text, '' order by id desc)
```

And in Oracle:

```
select listagg(text, '') within group (order by id)
```

Well, actually there is a portable way if you know the maximum number of values:

```
select concat(case when seqnum = 1 then text end,
              concat(case when seqnum = 2 then text end,
                     concat(case when seqnum = 3 then text,
                            . . .
                           )
                    )
             )
from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by id) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t;
```

Unfortunately, `concat()` in Oracle only takes two arguments so you have to keep nesting them.